# How to save file names with a different name?

Tags: shell-script, shell

I want my script to read from a listofNewNames and then save a new file under a new name which will be the first three letters of the file name plus a counter adding one for every file beginning with the same three letters.

Suppose these are my old and new file names-

listofFileNames: A77 A77 A77 A78 A78

listofNewNames: A7701 A7702 A7703 A7801 A7802 (prospective, listofNewNames is not intended to be saved)

```
COUNTER=0
for i in listofFileNames; do
while [$COUNTER -lt 5]
let "COUNTER=COUNTER+01"
done
newName=${oldfilename}${COUNTER}.L2_LAC_OC
done
```

This is so far what I have but whenever the letters change the counter has to re-start to 0 so the lenght of the file names is never 5.  It is, for example, 3 and then 2, depending on the amount of files.

I hope I had make myself clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would the 101st file be named?

Comment: Please mark an answer as solution or tell us what you need.

Answer (score 1):

See this:

```
ListOfFiles=("A77" "A77" "A77" "A78" "A78")
for oldfile in "${ListOfFiles[@]}"; do 
    COUNT=1; 
    while [[ -f "$(printf "%s%02d" ${oldfile} ${COUNT})" ]]; do 
        COUNT=$(($COUNT + 1)) 
    done 
    echo "NewName: $(printf "%s%02d" ${oldfile} ${COUNT})"
    touch "$(printf "%s%02d" ${oldfile} ${COUNT})"
done
```

at the moment the script will give you Filenames like

```
NewName: A7701
NewName: A7702
NewName: A7703
NewName: A7801
NewName: A7802
```

Answer (score 1):

```
last_name=""
listofFileNames=(A77 A77 A77 A78 A78)

for name in "${listofFileNames[@]}"; do
        test "$name" != "$last_name" && COUNTER=1
        last_name="$name"
        printf "%s%02d\n" "${name}" "${COUNTER}"
        ((COUNTER++))
done
```